# Обратный отсчёт времени на javascript

Tags: javascript

Мне надо сделать таймер обратного отсчета до 31 декабря. Более менее понимаю, каковым должен быть алгоритм:

1) переменная с текущим временем и 31 декабрям

2) потом надо узнать разницу в секундах между этими датами, да?

3) запустить таймер с помощью setInterval

4) каждый раз, когда пройдет один шаг (1 секунда), надо перезаписывать текущее время, да?

Помогите мне написать это на javascript.

Comment: примерно всё так.... а в каком моменте затык? не знаете как интервал посчитать между двумя датами? как запустить setInterval? как выводить каждую секунду сколько времени осталось?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, с setInterval-ом я уже работала, так что с этим проблем нет. Не могу понять как написать 4 пункт. Ведь именно в нем кроется главное - таймер не будет сбиваться. И да, как выводить каждую секунду сколько времени осталось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-нибудь в этом духе:

```js
const endTime = new Date('2017-12-31T23:59:59.999');
let updateTimer = () => {
  if (new Date() > endTime) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    let timeDiff = Math.floor((endTime - new Date()) / 1000);
    document.getElementById('timer').innerText = timeDiff;
  }
}
let timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
updateTimer();
```

```html
Осталось <span id="timer">???</span> сек.
```

Comment: вы уверены, что вычислять разницу каждую секунду просто необходимо, вместо того, чтобы однократно вычислить секунды и работать с ними? Кстати, а что на счет различных часовых поясов?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я подумала, что необходимо каждый раз вычислять секунды для того, чтобы таймер не сбивался, разве нет? А пояса - это такое) Это задание локальное, только на мой город, поэтому они не важны

Comment: @Yaant, спасибо большое) С минутами, часами и днями уже будет легче разобраться)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а что насчет часовых поясов? Как раз-таки Новый Год в разных часовых поясах наступает в разное время.

Comment: @Біпач достаточно до интервала вычислить разницу. записать секунды в переменную, а потом в setInterval просто уменьшать число на 1, вместо того, чтобы насиловать функции каждую секунду

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Думал об этом, но не стал выносить вычисление из таймера для упрощения примера. Из тех же соображений не стал разбивать результат на дни, минуты и секунды. :) Что касается часовых поясов, предположил, что пользователя будет интересовать его локальное время. :)

Comment: И кстати, не уверен во внутренностях реализации setInterval: если поток выполнения JS будет занят выполнением какого-то кода, скажем, три секунды, то после этого setInterval выполнится все три пропущенных раза, или всего один?

Comment: @Біпач предлагаю поанализировать и cтащить скрипты отсюда https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/ :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский надеюсь, вы увидите это мое обращение к вам. Пожалуйста, помогите в конвертацией. Я написала (и в частности увидела) вот такое: `var sec = Math.floor((endTime - new Date()) / 1000); /*секунди*/
            var d = (sec/(60*60*24));
            var h = sec/3600 ^ 0 ;
            var m = (sec-h*3600)/60 ^ 0 ;
            var s = sec-h*3600-m*60 ;`. Казалось бы, всё работает, но! Выходит вот такое 30.37553240740741 д. 729 ч. 00 мин. 46 сек. :С никак не могу разобраться. Может, вы в этом разбираетесь?

Comment: @Біпач https://jsfiddle.net/xocyuvpf/1/  .....а ведь могла вопрос задать на ruSO ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо вам огромное с: подумала, что не стоит открывать новый вопрос ради такого, казалось бы, пустяка. Да и времени в обрез) вы мен спасли с:

Comment: @Біпач  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/754181/191482 ;-)   там есть пример с плагином для js хых

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, о, а я пробовала использовать countdownjs, но что-то совсем запуталась. Кроме jQuery, Boostrap и fontawesome я ничего не использую. Спасибо за еще одно решение) А, и можно как-то с вами пообщаться?

Comment: @Біпач есть чаты https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com и главный https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но я без понятия как создать чат в отдельным человеком