# Как разницу дат привести к формату дни,часы,минуты,секунды?

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Пишу обратный отсчет до определенной даты. У меня есть конечная дата (31 декабря 2017) и текущая (она вычисляется каждый раз при перезагрузке страницы).
Соответсвенно у меня есть разница между датами в секундах:

```
var endTime = new Date('2017-12-31T23:59:59.999');
var timeDiff = Math.floor((endTime - new Date()) / 1000);
```

Я хочу выводить данные в виде `X д. Y ч. Z мин.  сек.`. Как правильно это сделать?

Я пишу:

```
var sec = Math.floor((endTime - new Date()) / 1000); 
var d = (sec / (60 * 60 * 24)); 
var h = sec / 3600 ^ 0; 
var m = (sec - h * 3600) / 60 ^ 0; 
var s = sec - h * 3600 - m * 60;
```

Но в итоге получается: `30.37553240740741 д. 729 ч. 00 мин. 46 сек.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мысль почти верная. Но в итоге достаточно поэтапно из общего числа секунд вычитать "крупные куски" начиная с дней и тогда при декомпозиции получится следующее:

```js
// Наша конечная дата
const endTime = new Date('2017-12-31T23:59:59.999');
let timerDiv = document.getElementById('test');
setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  // Берем разницу дат в секундах
  let delta = Math.floor((endTime - new Date()) / 1000);
  // Вычисляем количество ПОЛНЫХ дней
  let days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
  // А теперь вычитаем из секунд количество дней, выраженных в секундах
  delta -= days * 86400;
  // В оставшихся секунд вычленяем количество полных часов
  let hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
  // Также их потом вычитаем, выразив в секундах
  delta -= hours * 3600;
  // Из оставшихся секунд берем минуты
  let minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
  // Опять вычитаем
  delta -= minutes * 60;
  // И наконец секунды
  // В теории  деление по модулю на 60 не обязателен
  let seconds = delta % 60;
  // Итоговая дата
  let dateStr = `${days} д. ${hours} ч. ${minutes} мин. ${seconds} сек.`;

  timerDiv.innerText = dateStr;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

А вообще для обратного отсчета можно взять плагин на чистом *JS* - **[countdownjs](http://countdownjs.org/)** (см. демо http://countdownjs.org/demo.html), заменить английские буквы на русские и не париться :)

```js
const endTime = new Date('2017-12-31T23:59:59.999');
const pageTimer =  document.getElementById('pageTimer');
const counterStr = (ts) => pageTimer.innerHTML = `${ts.days} д. ${ts.hours} ч. ${ts.minutes} мин. ${ts.seconds} сек.`;

countdown((ts) => counterStr(ts), endTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mckamey/countdownjs/master/countdown.js"></script>
<div id="pageTimer"></div>
```

Comment: А разве нельзя просто создать новый `new Date(delta)` и он сам преобразует? (Возможно `new Date(delta+const)`)

Comment: @nick_n_a если вам что-то известно - напишите ответ