# Рассчитать время между датами

Tags: php

Есть две даты с временем в формате DATETIME (напр. 2017-12-28 15:00 и 2017-12-29 12:00 )

Каким образом получить дату и время от первой до второй даты?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php Почитайте тут

Comment: Каков часовой пояс?

Comment: @andreymal UTC+03:00

Comment: алгоритм тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754182/191482 ..... или надо другое что-то?

Comment: @Денис если в качестве одной из дат взять лето 2014 года, там тоже будет UTC+03:00?

Comment: @andreymal такой поздней даты не будет. начиная с 2017 года минимум

Comment: @Денис что если нашим депутатам в каком-нибудь 2019 году приспичит добавить один час к московскому времени? :) Я докапываюсь, потому что сам словил кучу проблем с часовыми поясами, когда 26 октября 2014 года из московского времени убрали один час, и хочу предостеречь вас от тех же проблем. Будьте осторожны, в общем

Comment: что это вообще такое ­— «дата от первой до второй даты»???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2017-12-28 15:00:00');
$datetime2 = date_create('2017-12-29 12:00');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R %a дней %h часов %i минут');
```

Проверка http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f673f829304db7748d6fcc9a163eef8ad9b69509

Подробнее читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php